# How to implement a login page with JSON Web Token in Ember app with express api

Tags: express, ember.js, jwt, passport.js, passport-local

I added authentication for my Express API following [this guide](https://scotch.io/@devGson/api-authentication-with-json-web-tokensjwt-and-passport#toc-registration-and-log-in-middleware) and after testing my secret-routes everything seems to work properly. Now my question is how can this be used in an Ember app login page. After receiving the secret token after a successful login how does the browser know you are signed in. How would one log out? How does the ember application know who is signed in? Is there any thing in particular security wise that I should be at tentative to while working on this?

Comment: you need to check for the presence of a token (maybe stored in localstorage or elsewhere), and then also check if the token is expired, and if the token's user id matches the current user id, if all that checks out, your app can assume the user is 'logged in'

Comment: Check [ember-simple-auth](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth) and [ember-simple-auth-token](https://github.com/jpadilla/ember-simple-auth-token)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use addons to handle most of the heavy lifting for you.

[ember-simple-auth-token](https://github.com/jpadilla/ember-simple-auth-token#authenticator) has setup directions that have you create a login route which will take a username / password and send it to your server for validation. The token response will then be available in your app until the user logs out.

The example looks like

```
import Controller from '@ember/controller';
import { inject } from '@ember/service';

export default Controller.extend({
  session: inject('session'),

  actions: {
    authenticate: function() {
      const credentials = this.getProperties('username', 'password');
      const authenticator = 'authenticator:token'; // or 'authenticator:jwt'

      this.get('session').authenticate(authenticator, credentials);
    }
  }
});
```

You also create the logout route which handles logging out of your app as well as sending any logout request to the server.

If possible you should align your server to the defaults, but you can configure nearly everything.

[Authentication Options](https://github.com/jpadilla/ember-simple-auth-token#json-web-token-authenticator-1)

```
ENV['ember-simple-auth-token'] = {
  tokenDataPropertyName: 'tokenData'; // Key in session to store token data
  refreshAccessTokens: true, // Enables access token refreshing
  tokenExpirationInvalidateSession: true, // Enables session invalidation on token expiration
  serverTokenRefreshEndpoint: '/api/token-refresh/', // Server endpoint to send refresh request
  refreshTokenPropertyName: 'refresh_token', // Key in server response that contains the refresh token
  tokenExpireName: 'exp', // Field containing token expiration
  refreshLeeway: 0 // Amount of time to send refresh request before token expiration
};
```

We've been very happy with this addon in production for 3 years and I'd highly recommend it.